# Regex Text Input Validation

Tags: regex, cognitoforms

I'm way in over my head here, but trying to learn.

Attempting to use text input validation on Cognito forms by way of a custom regular expression.

I'm trying to capture users work email in an online form. In the "work email" field they would only be able to enter the text to the left of the @ and then once they type "@" it'll automatically populates the "organization.com." I'll probably want to make sure that the user cant enter spaces, and other characters (ie:'*&^%$#!)

Been googling how to do this but no luck so far. I'm sure I'm using the wrong terminology to describe what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should be able to do it by learning the basics of HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: It looks to me like you should consider starting with some very basic examples or tutorials. It is hard to get help when the vocabulary to express these questions is missing, but this could be seen as a hint that some fundamentals may be missing. You say you have been googling, but what have you tried so far? Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

This does everything you need except handle the actual submission of the data.

```js
document.querySelector('input').oninput = function () {
  if (this.value.endsWith('@')) {
    this.value += 'organization.com';
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type=email pattern=.*@organization\.com$ title='name@organization.com' required />
  <button type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>
```